# regarding ftp_rawlist: what is file or directory number?

Tags: php, ftp

I've a question regarding ftp_rawlist...

ftp_rawlist returns an array as below

```
<code>array(3) {
[0]=>
string(65) "drwxr-x--- 3 vincent vincent 4096 Jul 12 12:16 public_ftp"
[1]=>
string(66) "drwxr-x--- 15 vincent vincent 4096 Nov 3 21:31 public_html"
[2]=>
string(73) "lrwxrwxrwx 1 vincent vincent 11 Jul 12 12:16 www -> public_html"
}</code>
```

Now, what is the number **3**, **15** and **1** here? what is it?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/477858/what-does-the-number-after-unix-linux-file-permissions-like-rw-rw-r-1-mea

Comment: I guessed that but was not clear. I got it. Now its crystal clear. Thanks man.